# Why couldn't early C compilers handle variable declarations between statements?

Tags: history, c, compilers, design-choices

In modern C, you may place variable declarations between statements:

```
do_something();
int x;
x = something_else();
```

However, older C compilers required that variables are declared before all statements:

```
int x;
do_something();
x = something_else();
```

(Page 33 of *The C Programmer's Handbook*, AT&T Bell Laboratories, 1984 states "Within a block, all declarations must precede the first statement."  Page 223 of *The C Programming Language*, Kernighan & Ritchie, 2nd edition 1988 defines a "compound statement" as `{` *declaration-list<sub>opt</sub>* *statement-list<sub>opt</sub>* `}`.)

**What was the reason (whether philosophical or practical) that early C compilers could not allow declarations between statements?**

You need to be much more specific than saying "compilers were dumb".  For example, the following code *was* supported by these same compilers:

```
do_something();

{
    int x;
    x = something_else();
}
```

Comment: This is just a guess, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but it wouldn't surprise me if the answer is a mix of "easier to lay out the stack frame in a single-pass compiler if the variable declarations come first" and "it was more common to see languages in the vein of Pascal where functions and procedures aren't single-block constructs and sequester variable declarations away from the code in a special block at the top". Wikipedia has an un-cited claim that the latter was motivated by the former.

Comment: Declarations _should always be_ at the top of the block, AND _stay off my grass_ :)

Comment: @BrianH It's ["get off my lawn"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_kids_get_off_my_lawn!) </pedant> :P

Comment: @ssokolow Yes, that's right. But my way stops me having to repeat myself in an endless loop...

Comment: @BrianH  I was more concerned with the "lawn" vs. "grass" than the "get off " vs. "stay off".

Comment: Because they didn't have to?

Comment: tl,dr: C was originally intended to be a "single pass" compiler (well, locally), so like many other compilers of that era, you had to declare something before you could use it, and it was just easier to have all declarations first.

Comment: Re "compilers were dumb". you have it exactly backwards.  It's the compilers (or rather, the people who made the design decision) that allow variable declarations just anywhere that are dumb.  It's an ongoing, if minor, cause of unreadable code.

Comment: @jamesqf, That's a question of taste, and I know people—good people, some of 'em—who might disagree with yours. They might ask, how does it make my code more "readable" if I write `double x;` ten lines above the place where I write `x = ...;` instead of just writing one line, `double x = ...;` ?

Comment: @ssokolow A real pedant wouldn’t close XML tags without opening them first.

Comment: @jamesqf: Making the `restrict` qualifier work without ambiguous corner cases in the specification requires making a distinction between creating a pointer object with a certain initial value, versus modifying the value of an already existing object; in order for that to be practical, it would need to be possible to create and initialize pointer objects in the middle of a block.  Perhaps that wouldn't matter given the badly written so-called "formal" specification for `restrict`, but it should matter if the construct was better specified.

Comment: @user3840170 \*chuckle* Ahh, but these aren't XML tags. They're an early form of Internet slang derived from the `</g>` "grin tag", and they operate on the reverse of the self-closing SGML tags HTML inherited. To explicitly open one is a minor faux pas.

Comment: @Solomon Slow: Because instead of having all your (non external) variable declarations in one convenient place, you have to look through the code to find them.  And you can write a simple declaration "double x, y, z;" instead of confusingly combining 3 declarations and assignments.

Comment: @jamesqf - but by declaring a variable at exactly the point I need it, then I **don't** have to look back through the code at all.  (And it's never 'not initialized' either).

Comment: @another-dave: It would often be helpful for languages to have a single level of "temporary" variables whose scope would end at an "end temporary variable scope" marker separate from normal scope, and something more idiomatic than `if(1) // scoping block` to indicate that a compound statement is being used for variable scoping.  Declaring variables mid-block and having their lifetime extend to 'whenever' may be the best one can do in C, but I think there should be a cleaner way of indicating when variable's lifetimes end, especially when using things like `restrict`.

Comment: What's wrong with  `{ int mytemp; .... }` ?  Why `if (1)`  ?

Comment: @supercat: Well, whether having the restrict qualifier is a different argument.

Comment: @jamesqf: The `restrict` qualifier is a good concept, but the specification does a horrible job with corner cases  The qualifier would have been fine and useful if it were defined in terms of expression syntax and program structure rather than coincidental value equality.  For example, I think `p1+intval` was intended to be based upon `p1`, regardless of `intval`, and it should be based upon `p1`, even if `intval` happens to be `(p2-p1)`.  The present definition doesn't require compilers to recognize that, however, and neither clang nor gcc does.

Comment: @another-dave  I can't remember the last time I saw "naked inline curly braces" around a snippet just to lift the stack. It scares the littlies. For some reason it is not taught. They expect a function.

Comment: @mckenzm - They need to be taught?  Why don't they just read the grammar?  (Somewhat in jest; but having programmed in FORTRAN, which had to explain its syntax in words, finding the ALGOL 60  *Revised Report* was a breath of fresh air)

Answer (score 39):

Some early compilers, such as the ones described in the 1974 C reference manual, required that all automatic object declarations within a function precede the first executable code therein.  Imposing this restriction made it possible for compilers to know the stack-relative offset of a function's arguments before it had to process any code that used them. Easing this restriction increased the amount of compiler complexity necessary to avoid gross inefficiencies, though the amount of added complexity could vary considerably depending upon the target platform, downstream build tools (e.g. sophistication of the assembler and linker), and tolerance for inefficient code.

Many compilers targeted platforms where some amount of interleaving between declarations and code could be accommodated reasonably conveniently and efficiently, and thus accepted constructs that the earliest compilers could not.  Allowing arbitrary intermixing of declarations and other statements, however, can cause some severe complications if execution branches from a spot within a variable's scope to a spot that is within its lifetime but precedes its scope.  Requiring that all declarations within a block precede the first statement within that block is more restrictive than would be necessary to guard against that, but is nonetheless effective for that purpose.

As far as your third example (a new declaration within a nested block) any branch targets that precede the nested `int x` declaration would be outside the block containing `x`, and thus could not be reached without ending the lifetime of `x`. Further, it would not be unreasonable for compilers to generate code that adjusts the stack pointer when entering or leaving a block containing automatic object declarations, since doing so would reduce the stack requirements of function calls that are performed within the function but not within the block.

Note that the C89 Standard deliberately excludes constructs that were widely supported, but for which the authors of the Standard did not think support would be universally practical.  I think the authors of the Standard should have been willing to recognize that some constructs should be broadly but not necessarily universally supported, and recognized a category of "limited" implementations which would be required to reject programs they couldn't process usefully, but would be required to meaningfully process programs they accept.  If someone is trying to run a C compiler on a machine with 48K of RAM, a compiler that omits features the person can do without may be more useful than one which tries to include everything that should be supported by compilers running on larger systems.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130974/discussion-on-answer-by-supercat-why-couldnt-early-c-compilers-handle-variable).

Answer (score 18):

**TLDR: most languages in 1969/70 had declarations first.**

BCPL had data declarations first within a block, and while the reference manuals for B on [dmr's (preserved) website](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/) only specify declaration before use, (corrected) the tutorial specifically says "all declarations must
precede executable statements" (in a function). Standard FORTRAN required 'specification' statements (if used at all; they could be omitted for scalars using the implicit typing, as davidbak reminded me) first in a subprogram, and COBOL had them in a 'division' before any code although after some environmental stuff (both still do for a given program-unit, although both now allow nested program units with their own declarations *after* the code). Pascal not only required declarations before code, it ordered them in subgroups: first constants, then types, then variables. Algol60 had declarations first in a block but allowed nested blocks (both like C), and IINM Jovial also; Algol68 relaxed this, along with *many* other things, but was widely regarded as unimplementable on small machines like the PDP-11 (and later Interdata) used for Unix/C. Somewhat similarly, PL/1 allowed declarations anywhere, but was the language of Multics, the system against whose bloat and cost Unix and C rebelled -- and even in PL/1 it was generally regarded as better style to put declarations at the top of a procedure or at least block.

BASIC of the day declared only arrays, and APL didn't have any declarations that I recall. LISP was, well, LISP; you wouldn't look there for ideas on designing something like C. And IIRC a popular textbook of the day on programming basics was "Data Structures Plus Algorithms" -- note the order.

"If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: re FORTRAN - my IBSYS FORTRAN IV manual merely says 'The type statements [by which it means REAL, INTEGER, DOUBLE PRECISION, etc.] must precede the first appearance of the variable(s) to which they refer in any executable, NAMELIST, or DATA statement'.  This boils down only to specification before use. The only 'must be at the top' specification statement seems to be COMMON.

Comment: It's been decades since I learned FORTRAN II (my first language) but it didn't even require declarations at all, right?  It had implicit typing integer vs float by first letter of the variable name.  A common error, IIRC, was misspelling an identifier = new var.  (Fortunately, there was none of this upper-case/lower-case nonsense we have today to worry about: your punch cards were upper case only.)  But even more important: FORTRAN didn't require a stack to allocate local subprogram variables and didn't have anything to clean up afterward: No recursion allowed!  No stack.  Everything "static".

Comment: Were Unix and C a _rebellion_ against Multics and PL/I in any way?  Considered at the time, I mean, not retrospectively.  I thought I read that Unix was a pragmatic reaction to the fact that the OS group at Bell Labs didn't have the funding to keep working with Multics, or to get their _own_ Multics.  They had to roll their own with what they had, and what they had were dinky little computers (compared to the GE645).

Comment: @davidbak - there was DIMENSION, which had to appear before first use of the array variable.  But no 'type' declarations.

Comment: Heck, MySQL functions still require all declarations at the top...

Comment: @another-dave Not sure about the pre-standardisation Fortrans but standard Fortran of any version I am aware of require all declarations to precede all executable statements in the program unit.

Comment: @VladimirF -  I have a duplicated 'cheat sheet' for the Purdue University Fast Fortran Translator (PUFFT) at Imperial College, and it lists 'incompatibilities with IBFTC' (IBM's 7094 Fortran IV) which include 'type statements must precede all executable statements'.  So some compilers had the limitation, but not the IBM compilers.

Comment: But Fortran is an interesting case.  Since it implements 'implicit declaration on first use of a name', which could occur anywhere, there would seem to be no reason why an explicit type declaration **can't** occur anywhere before first use.

Comment: @another-dave It is a numbered constrain't in the standard. That means that the compiler is *required* to diagnose it as an error. To allow declarations inside a program unit Fortran 2008 introduced a `block` construct (something like`{   }` in C). There is no technical reason why it wouldn't be possible, it was a design choice by X3J3.

Comment: I'm talking about the Fortran of the 1950s  and 1960s, though.

Comment: @VladimirF - Those early FORTRANs _were_ standardized.  Not by ISO or ANSI though.  By IBM.  If you had a "FORTRAN" compiler that didn't compile IBM FORTRAN - you didn't actually have a FORTRAN compiler, you had something else that may have been useful ... but it wasn't FORTRAN.

Comment: @davidbak: De facto standards are often better than "official" standards that suffer "design-by-committee-itis".  Given a choice between characterizing constructs that are sometimes useful as illegitimate, characterizing constructs that are sometimes unsupportable as legitimate, or recognizing that different implementations can and should support different constructs, the C89 Standard opted to do none of those things, but instead ignore any such constructs but let implementations that could support them do so as a form of "conforming language extension" outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

Comment: @supercat - I agree about de facto standards, yes, and I understand your point about the limits of standards' juristictions, but I wouldn't use the C89 standard as a reference point since it _also_ introduced trigraphs (including in _comments_) so I'm not sure those guys had their heads screwed on tight back then ...

Comment: @davidbak: Trigraphs in comments aren't as bad as trigraphs in string and character literals.  Instead of supporting that abomination, the Standard should have specified a means of indicating that a particular character outside the C character set should behave as a backslash, except that escaping that character should yield itself (escaping a forward slash should yield a backslash regardless of whether the escape character is a backslash).  Unless an execution platform has characters that aren't in the source character set, there's no meaningful way to process trigraphs...

Comment: ...in a string literal except when a trigraph backslash is being used as an escape.  If the source character set doesn't have a brace character, and a compiler doesn't know of any difference between source and target character sets, how could the compiler sensibly process a string literal like `"??<Enclosed in braces??>"`?

Comment: @davidbak There really uses the word "standardization" too freely. At least in the context of traditional languages like Fortran, Algol, COBOL, Scheme and so on. What is understood by standardization of Fortran is summarized in https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1500774.1500877  IBM of course played a very important role in Fortran 66 formulation, but there were already several other vendors by the early 1960s with various extensions and incompatibilities.

Comment: @VladimirF: Calling the ISO's C language specifications "standards" is an even bigger abuse of the term, since they waive normative authority over almost everything.  Because C89 allows implementations to extend the language in almost any fashion when the Standard doesn't mandate any particular behavior, the authors saw no need to specify ways of accomplishing everything programmers might need to do.  This would have been fine if compiler writers consistently understood that if the behavior of an action is both specified and characterized as Undefined, they should give priority to...

Comment: ...the behavioral specification in the absence of an obvious or documented reason why they doing otherwise would let them better fulfill their customers' needs, but means the Standards utterly fail to define any category of "conformance" which is meaningful when writing programs for tasks that cannot be accomplished with "100% portable" code, including *all* non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations.

Comment: @VladimirF: specification-part first is in numbered _syntax rules_ in F90 up (and the processor must be _able_ to diagnose them, not necessarily by default), but in F66 (current when C was created) and even F77 there were no required diagnostics at all.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I do not believe I said it was always there. I said that it *is* required. And that no standard allowed it.

Comment: @supercat There are many places where standard allows compiler extensions and processor dependent behaviour. That is not the same as undefined behaviour. That is perfectly allowed and standard conforming, but platform dependent. Nevertheless, in the realm of scientific and engineering computing, where Fortran is used the most, it makes big sense to strive for portability. In C, when doing drivers, embedded stuff or whatever, the needs and possibilities are very different.

Comment: @VladimirF: Where does that bleeping myth come from?  The phrase "non-portable or erroneous" in no way excludes "non-portable, but entirely correct", and the published Rationale explicitly states that UB was intended to, among other things, "identify avenues of conforming language extension".  The only reason freestanding implementations can do anything useful is that they process constructs "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" in ways not contemplated by the Standard.

Comment: @supercat I have no idea what you are talking about and how it is supposed to be connected to my previous comment. In particular, the words you quote in the "" quotes do not appear in my comments.

Comment: @VladimirF: While it might be useful to have standards for a scientific or verifiable computing dialects of C, the way many constructs are specified in the "C Standard" is too sloppy to be suitable for that purpose.  The concept of "effective type" was a compromise to avoid having to recognize different dialects, but it is sufficiently sloppily defined as to needlessly impede low-level programming while being impossible to process correctly without needlessly foregoing what should be useful optimizations.

Comment: @supercat This is just a collection of random words, isn't it?

Comment: @VladimirF: My quotes are from the Standard or rationale documents.  The myth I'm referring to is the notion that the Standard uses the term "Undefined Behavior" solely for erroneous constructs.

Comment: @VladimirF: A good language for high-end computing needs to have a specification which is much better written than the "C Standard".  The C89 Standard was never intended to describe such a language, and the Standard would need to be substantially reworked to be suitable for that purpose.

Comment: C89 is completely obsolete.

Answer (score 9):

Automatic variables like those are often stored on the stack. This means for each function, the first thing the generated code (at the time, assembly, not machine code) does is reserve space on the stack. To do that, it needs to know all the variables and their sizes.

Modern compilers will without trouble go through all the source code of the function and find out all the variables, and then generate all the code (and a lot more, including optimisation).

But if you want to build the simplest compiler possible, running on systems with very little memory, being able to generate the assembly as you process input is a big advantage (rather than storing a lot of things in memory and *then* output the assembly).

To do that, you need to have all those declarations before the first line of code. This way, your compiler goes like this:

- process variable declarations: make note of their names, sizes, (constant) initialisers, and the offset you will place them at on the stack
- output stack adjustment
- output initialisation
- start processing statements and output assembly for each statement as you process it

Of course nowadays with GiB of RAM everywhere this seems pointless, but at the time, anything you could read-process-output-forget was a big bonus.

Comment: The benefits of such simplification is dwarfed by the complexity of optimizers that spend more time trying to "optimize" large parts of many programs than would have been spent executing them naively (in many programs, the majority of of the code will execute on average less than twice each time the program executes) but I think the maintainers of the C Standard have lost sight of one of the design goals of C.

Answer (score 7):

The C language was not suddenly specified first and then made. C language was developed based on B language, which was a simplification on BCPL systems programming language, and C evolved a few years with new features that were needed and it became popular.

These languages (BCPL, B, C) were used to make the system level tools and utilities and thus were compiled on very small systems and thus needed very simple and they were only needed to support strict lexical parsing to be able to do what compilers do - parse structured text and output binary code. They were intended to have some medium level language so it was not necessary to write everything in system specific assembly language from scratch.

This is in contrast to other languages like Algol-68, which was an application programming language to produce higher level programs.

When C became popular, people also started to use it for applications, so at that point C programs became more and more complex and only at this point most likely people who were application programmers started to miss the feature.

Over the times computers got faster, got more memory, got improved language parser libraries, etc, so basically nothing prevented this but compiler implementations and code were typically adhering to the de facto standard, which later on became the C89 standard.

Many compilers extended beyond the standard and supported this feature as a non-standard extension before the feature was officially included in the C99 standard.

It was included in C99 because it was already found as a useful feature in Algol 68 and C++ programming languages.

The problem with standards is that even if compilers with extensions existed before, you had to conform to standards to be able to have portable code. If you used extensions, the scope could be limited as different compilers might have divergent implementations how to do things.

For example there might be contractual rules or regulations that mandate how you should write compliant code say for example medical devices or military equipment, and they might not allow custom extensions or might be limited to one compiler that has been validated for the work.

If you were required to write safety critical code using MISRA guidelines, they only included support for C99 in 2012, as the previous standard in 2004 stated that there were no commercial embedded compilers supporting C99 available.

So even if technically possible and available, you may not be able to use extensions outside standards for some reason even if you wanted to, or you may not even want to, if you want to support older systems with older compilers that have no support for C99 or similar extensions.

Comment: C was invented in 1974.  The first standard wasn't published until 1989, and its purpose was merely to describe features that were common among all existing C dialects, and not to imply that implementations that could support useful constructs beyond those mandated shouldn't do so when practical.

Comment: I can stand with all said in this answer (even upvoted). Just, it doesn't answer the question why some compilers were restricted (as said by the OP), or why it was put into the papers in the first place. It is kind of arguing in hindsight about today, isn't it?

Comment: It is impossible to write a non-trivial Strictly Conforming C Program for a freestanding implementation, but by definition every piece of source text that is accepted by at least one conforming C compiler somewhere in the universe is a "Conforming C Program".  As such, the notion of conforming to the Standard isn't really meaningful, at least with respect to freestanding implementations or programs for them.

Comment: @supercat Ansi C included several changes from the previous C "standard" (i.e. the language described in K&R first edition). Most notably, it included the modern function definition and prototyping syntax.

Comment: @JeremyP: C++ made its debut in 1986, and C compilers started supporting the style of function declarations used by C++ prior to the publication of C89.  The old syntax would have been rendered obsolete if C89 had recognized that some platforms could use a more efficient calling convention for prototyped function, but interfacing with outside code may require that a function use the non-prototyped calling convention, and if C99 had specified that VLA arrays in a function signature have incomplete types that will be resolved once the end of the signature is reached.

Comment: @supercat Ha!  The ANSI C standard innovated a great deal from the then-current language.  It completely changed the way functions are declared, for example.  I remember the run-up to ANSI C was like new Christmas presents all the time, early waiting for compilers to implement the new features.

Comment: Other changes IIRC include `void`, making structure members specific to each structure instead of global offsets, and features in the preprocessor like token pasting and stringizing.

Comment: @JDługosz: Which came first--the introduction of those features into C++, or the publication of the C Standard?  Which came first--compilers that supported those features, or the publication of the C Standard?

Comment: @supercat The new-style declarations were invented for C++ first.  The ANSI C "prototype" was based on this.  The compilers were tracking the _draft_ standard and ideas and thus compilers were extant when the final standard was actually completed.  One anomaly is that the `const` keyword was proposed for C before C++ was a thing, by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: BTW, to give you an idea how small the compilers still were at the time, I was running the C compiler from a 360K floppy disk on a IBM PC.  Source code was on a second floppy disk; I had to change disks to run the linker.

Comment: @JDługosz: I think C compilers would still have incorporated support for prototypes form C++ whether or not there were a standard, much as they incorporated support for // comments a decade before they were incorporated into C99.  If the Committee were really willing to innovate, they could have offered a good model of console I/O which would be supportable via libraries on both Unix and non-Unix systems, with the proviso that on some systems getch() might return an error code to indicate that raw character I/O was unavailable.

Comment: @JDługosz: All that would have required would have been to specify a standard function that applications must call before using `getch()` to do whatever is necessary (if anything) to prepare for raw console I/O, a function they must call after that before using `getchar()` based I/O to do whatever is necessary (if anything) to switch back, and a `getch()` function to perform raw I/O.

Comment: @supercat You're saying that if they didn't get all the major compiler writers and other insiders into a room and decide that C ought to have prototypes and work out the exact syntax and meaning, that each vendor would have added some kind of prototype as an extension, individually, in the same time frame?

Comment: @JDługosz: Given that C++ had *already* worked out the syntax and meaning was, why not? There are a few good things that emerged from standardization, like stdarg.h and canonical locations for standard library functions in standard library headers, but the Committee should have been a lot more willing to use the term "SHOULD". For example, if a C compiler is targeting 8-bit micro like the Commodore 64 which has 40-bit floating-point routines in ROM, which would be more useful: one where both `float` and `double` use that 40-bit floating-point type, or one where `double` has more precision?

Comment: @JDługosz: Specifying that doubles SHOULD have at least ten full decimal digits of precision would have left room for implementer judgment, while allowing programmers to expect that compilers *which don't document an inability to support such precision* would support it. Mandated report for recursion was another major burden on some platforms. A load or store of a static 16-bit object on the Z80 takes 16 cycles.  One for an automatic-duration object takes 38. Further, call/return overhead for a function that uses any automatic-duration objects is 71 cycles, versus 27 for functions that don't.

Comment: @JDługosz: Returning to the main subject at issue, if a compiler that required all that all objects used in a function precede any executable code therefor could build programs thirty seconds faster than one that accommodated freer placement, I think a lot of programmers would have, at least for a few years, been willing to accept the syntactic limitations in exchange for faster build times.  As computers got faster, the perceived need for programmers to accommodate such systems would have naturally diminished.

Comment: @supercat "if a compiler that required all that all objects used in a function precede any executable code". That's never been true for C (well not since TheCPL 1st edition). C only required that definitions precede the first executable statement in the same block.

Comment: @JeremyP: The 1974 C Reference Manual specified that the language at that time was not block scoped.  The amount of difficulty posed by supporting block scopes will depend upon the target platform and the level of linker sophistication.  Ritchie likely decided the benefits of block scoping were worth the cost on the platfomrs he was using, but people targeting platforms wimpier than Ritchie's PDP-11 might have favored other tradeoffs.

Comment: @supercat In 1974 the language was still evolving quite rapidly. By the time of TheCPL block scoped declarations were an explicit thing. Furthermore, block scoped definitions simplify the language parser, since function blocks and other blocks have the same syntax.

Comment: @JeremyP: It's necessary to treat a closing brace that ends a function differently from one that occurs in a mid-function block, so I don't see any real simplification there.  Limiting variables to the start of a function would allow for faster build cycles on some platforms, and I think the Standard should have recognized a distinction between "full" and "limited" versions of the language, with the intention that if a compiler for a particular platform accepts a reasonably-portable program designed for that platform, it could be expected to work.

Comment: @supercat In what way is it necessary to treat the closing brace of a function differently? It's the same as any other block. What code you generate after you exit the scope is different, but it's different for every type of block.

Comment: @JeremyP: A declaration like `float foo;` can have three fundamentally different meanings depending upon whether it appears before a function, between a function header and the first opening brace, or between the first and last opening brace.  This is true whether or not one supports block scopes.  On many platforms, a compiler that doesn't have to accommodate block scopes will be able to process code more expeditiously than would be possible if support for block scopes were necessary, and while I haven't any of the minimalist compilers that ran on machines like the Apple II or C64, ...

Comment: ...my understanding is that many of them processed a restricted dialect of the language which didn't support everything that was added between "C74" and "K&R1".  Note that while some compilers may have used a recursive function to process nested blocks, many compilers would instead keep a count of nested blocks and a list of pending labels and the block levels where they should be output.  In such a design, the last close brace of a function would switch the compiler from "executable code mode" to "inter-function declaration mode".

Comment: @supercat `float foo` appearing in file scope or as a parameter declaration is irrelevant. They are both outside of blocks. Also, it's impossible to write a C compiler without some level of recursive block definitions because they can be embedded recursively. Allowing declarations at the start of any block eliminates a special case. It makes the parser simpler.

Comment: @JeremyP: If one requires that struct *definitions* must always be at file scope (declare inner structures before including them within outer structures), the only state that needs to be kept associated with braces is a counter, and an array to say what label to output, if any, when the brace level is reduced from N to N-1; the counter can use a special sentinel value within a function definition.  Dirt simple, compared with what's required to support scopes.

Comment: @JeremyP: Note that some platforms can efficiently support recursion, but some can't; a compiler for a platform that can't efficiently support recursion may need to be designed differently from a compiler for one that can.  Further, if there were a recognized "bootstrap" subset of the language, full-featured compilers could be bootstrapped on any platform with adequate resources for which a "bootstrap C" compiler exists, possibly written in assembly language.

Answer (score 4):

Early C had to be as small as possible!

Remember that Version 7 Unix, released in 1979, and ran on the DEC PDP-11. The PDP-11 had only a 16-bit address bus, and could only address 64KB of memory.

Quite simply, the early C compiler had to be as simple as possible! *There was not room* for anything that might complicate the compiler.

Early C was an elegant and practical little language. Served well as "high level assembly". But of necessity had to be light on features.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how "declarations come first" translates to "small code size". In either case, you're basically parsing a line of tokens and sticking whatever you come up into a linked list or other collection.

Comment: @OmarL single pass compiler says what?

Comment: PDP-11 ISA has 16-bit logical addresses (from 16-bit registers), but even the earliest machines had an 18-bit _bus_ (Unibus) -- which without memory-management option could handle only 56KB memory because 8KB space was used for I/O. Per [a recap paper by Ritchie](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html) the initial machine (an 11/20) had only 24KB. By [the 1978 BSTJ paper](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cacm.html) it was an 11/70 (which had KSU-I&D MM and 22-bit MassBus nominally capable of 4G) fitted with 768K (shared by multiple users).

Comment: @user253751 what?

Comment: I find it interesting that 1974 C allowed declaration of arrays within arrays without requiring them to be enclosed in structures, since the type system could have been a lot simpler without that allowance, especially if one didn't need quality diagnostics.  Were it not for the concept of arrays within arrays, there would be no need for the type system to keep track of array sizes after space was allocated for them.

Comment: Possibly, but possibly not.  There were many ways to adapt big software (big for its time), including compilers, to run on little computers.  A popular technique for compilers were multiple passes.  As in, a _lot_ of passes.  E.g.: The Concurrent Pascal compiler (Caltech, 1975) was a 7 pass compiler that self-hosted on a 16K word 11/45 - _none_ of those passes were "optimization" (not even peephole optimization) - all were to reduce the source language to a compiled VM code. The book describing this says its inspirations included: Gier Algol, 9 passes (1963) and Siemens 3003 COBOL, 10 passes.

Comment: Specifically, the infamous GOTO statement would be harder to implement.  

 1. If you transfer control to a different location within the same block, that is trivial.  
 2. If you transfer control from within one block to another, then you have to account for differences in the variables on the stack.
 3. If you allow variables to be declared ad-hoc, then that must be accounted for.  How do you do this?  Should the compiler implicitly move all declarations to the beginning of the block?  Should it create an implicit scope block?  As you can see, it's more complicated.

Comment: Yes, you could add features to the compiler by doing multiple passes. Keep in mind, CPUs were thousands of times slower than present. Disks were also much slower. Today you might compile a modest-sized source file in under a second. If you had a choice between a compiler (light on features) that compiled a source file in minutes, or another (feature-laden) that compiled in hours - which would you choose?

Comment: @PrestonL.Bannister: Compiler-performance issues often remain just as relevant today as in years past.  It's common for compilers to spend more time trying to optimize a piece of code than the code would spend executing if processed by a single-shot compiler with nothing beyond some basic peephole and register-caching optimizations (e.g. not particularly trying to keep useful things in registers, but using registers in round-robin fashion keeping track of what was in them, and reusing registers that held useful values).

Comment: Not sure what you were referring to but neither Concurrent Pascal nor Algol 58/60 were feature-laden languages ... multiple passes were necessary to compile the bare language within the size limit.  16Kword!  (32KB). `printf ("hello world");` takes 13KB using [`musl`](https://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html) for the executable alone, figure 3KB for minimal operating system, ok, now write a Pascal compiler with the 16KB you have left ... oh wait ... you didn't leave any room for _data_ ...

Comment: @davidbak: How big would printf be with floating-point support removed?  The Turbo Pascal IDE for CP/M was 26K, and that included a rather powerful text editor that Turbo later released as a code blob that was about 10K.  Using multiple passes can save memory if one needs to keep the source code and generated machine code in RAM simultaneously (as was the case for the earliest compilers), but would offer far fewer benefits if e.g. a machine had a couple tape drives at its disposal.

Comment: @davidbak: I would think that it would be practical to design a C-like language implementation for an 8080-based Altair with a tape reader and punch which could run comfortably in 16K and use a single-pass compilation model where the compiler must first be fed a tape containing all shared global objects and forward declarations of all shared functions, followed by tape(s) with any desired source files that should use those declarations, and for each source file would produce a tape which could be processed by a simple linking loader.  To "link" a program, simply concatenate...

Comment: ...the tapes produced for all of the translation units therein.  Adding any global objects or functions would require rebuilding everything, but otherwise individual translation units could be recompiled and "relinked" simply by removing the compiler output from the old module and splicing in the new.  If one has a floating-point library linked at a fixed address, and included code for that at the end of a tape to be loaded, such a build system could probably accommodate most practical programs that would be able to fit in memory once completely built.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the language definition specified, at least in K&R,"The C Programming Language", first edition (1978).

The BNF for a "compound statement" was (K&R, Appendix A, 9.2)

```
compound statement :
   { declaration-list statement-list }
```

(ignoring some details)

and for a function body (K&R, Appendix A, 10.1)

```
function-body :
   declaration-list compound-statement
```

thus defining that declarations preceded statements.

This followed not just BCPL and B, but also other "modern" block-structured languages like the Algols and Pascal, so it was the way programmers expected to work, and contemporary compilers could easily handle it.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether compilers of that era would more typically allocate and release stack space on entering/exiting a block, or would typically consolidate allocations?  If the former, it's easy to see how block scoping could allow programs to run with less stack space than would otherwise be needed, though allowing `goto` to enter and leave scopes which allocate and release stack space would add significant cost to a single-shot compiler, since any forward jump would either need to include a stack-adjustment instruction that would often adjust the stack by zero bytes...

Comment: ...or else forward gotos that enter or leave blocks would need to target a springboard which is placed after the rest of the function's code, and which would adjust the stack before jumping back into the main line code.  Both of those approaches would be possible, but would increase compiler complexity versus having programs place all automatic object declarations before any executable code.

Comment: @supercat my "goto" (sorry) for this is Bornat's "Understanding and writing compilers" which I still think is excellent (if a bit ICL-1900 oriented!). Indeed, function/block prologues built stack frames, holding both arguments (for functions) and locals ("auto" to C people). But I can't remember how Bornat handled non-local gotos.

Comment: The question already cites K&R, and is about ***why*** they chose such.

Comment: @DrSheldon it cites a much later edition of K&R.

Comment: @supercat I hate feeling so old. I worked on computers, such as the HP 21xx, which had no concept of a hardware stack register and where the return address for a function call was jammed into the first address of the called subroutine and where a return used an indirect jump instruction. You ask a question about stack space that assumes, I think, that stacks always existed. It took years and years to finally recognize that concept as worthy of hardware support. I worked on o/s and compilers in 1974 and learned c while working on Unix v6 kernel. I may add if I find some time and inclination.

Comment: @jonk: Efficiently handling of recursion essentially requires a means of storing and accessing variables on some kind of RAM-based stack, whether it be a hardware stack, or whether (as on older ARM devices) there's simply a convention of using a certain register as a stack pointer but nothing in the hardware would care about what register is used for that purpose.  Personally, I think the C Standard should have allowed for implementations where all objects would need to be statically allocated, especially since that would both allow massive efficiency improvements on some platforms...

Comment: ...and also because it would allow the Standard to define a meaningful category of "safe" conformance: if a Safely Conforming Implementation is give a Selectively Conforming Program, and the translation and execution environments satisfy all documented requirements, behavior should be limited to either processing the code as mandated, or indicating in documented fashion a refusal to do so; time spent without doing anything, even if infinite, should not be considered a "behavior".

Comment: @supercat Recursion was *a thing* circa 1970. DEC's PDP-11 manuals (which I still have on my shelf) made sure to call it out, for example. Because... well, because they knew that the ideas had to be introduced carefully as many active target-reading programmers weren't entirely well versed in those ideas. Re-entry is yet another thing that was carefully explained. And the idea of co-routines, yet another. There's nothing you've said that is anything but well-deepened inside of me.

Comment: @supercat Though you make a lot of it here, efficiency of execution wasn't at the top of anyone's list (except as a matter of academia.) Aside from core memory, which to this very day nothing else is quite like, we were mostly dealing with rather small amounts of fast random access memory (VERY EXPENSIVE) and slow washing-machine sized "drum recorders" with maybe 8k byte and mag-tapes, etc. The computer was "mostly waiting." Even compilation itself was often "rolled in" in pieces at a time because of the lack of RAM.

Comment: @jonk: If one is trying to design a usable C-dialect compiler for a platform like the 8080, treating all declarations as having static duration would make the compiler simpler and generate much more efficient code to access objects than would be practical if using the stack.  Something like `x += y;` would be `ld hl,(x) / ld de,(y) / add hl,de / ld (x),hl` if `x` and `y` are statically allocated.  Ten bytes.  If they're on the stack, then `ld hl,ofs x / add hl,sp / ex de,hl / ld hl,ofs y / add hl,sp / ld a,(de) / add a,(hl) / ld (de),a / inc de / inc hl / ld a,(de) / adc a,(hl) / ld (de),a`...

Comment: ...at 17 bytes would probably be about as efficient as a compiler could generate, being even slightly clever with keeping the addresses of the two objects in DE and HL.  If memory is at all an issue, having the code be seven bytes bigger and a lot slower would seem like a pretty major loss even if execution speed weren't an issue.

Comment: @supercat I'm specifically avoiding a discussion about static duration (or 'program lifetime') auto variables, because it is a diversion from what I was slightly flummoxed over in skimming this entire page. There's no question that autos can be implemented as statics and pretty much any good 8051 C compiler supports that idea, actively. It's too important to ignore. But by then, we were a decade and more of hardware development later, too. I suppose you've already read Ritchie's discussion about the development of C [here](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)?

Comment: @supercat I forgot to mention the obvious. DEC took great pains -- long, long sections of crafted writing -- in their PDP-11 manuals to explain all of the benefits of their addressing modes and how many different ways stacks could be used. But they started out with the basics of a stack, why it is important, etc. These ideas weren't "ambient" or well-gathered at the time. Many practicing programmers had been exposed in class to such concepts as one class of programming solutions among many. Like sorting or walking trees might be introduced, but not as a matter of hardware support.

Comment: @supercat I was square in the middle of the process of rolling out such ideas (hardware stacks, multiple types of co-routines, threading concepts of shared static lifetime variables but separate stacks, the "new" basic program memory model that included a stack section, etc., to a larger programming public. (Which is almost ***nothing*** like the larger programming public of today, as most of us were well-trained and many were either abstract or applied mathematicians attracted to the idea of using computers.)

Comment: @supercat All of us (and that includes me) who haven't lived through something tend to only gather up a simplified view because it's simply not possible to do otherwise. There's a funny story about a country of map-makers that started out making maps of the world. At first, their maps occupied a library. But then, an entire city. Then, their entire country. Their final map of the world was as big and detailed ... as the world itself! We have to simplify our views when we didn't live it. I get that. But why things were done and not done? The answers are nuanced well beyond what I see here.

Comment: @jonk: I've read the piece before; skimming through it now, I didn't notice any discussion of whether or not to allow variables to be declared within inner scoping blocks.  Depending upon the platform and downstream code generation tools, support for that may be cheap and simple, or expensive and complicated.  A design decision which was made before the 1974 dialect, but which I find somewhat curious, was making an array's dimension be an aspect of its type.  Absent that, if one didn't care about issuing good diagnostics for erroneous programs, and if code and data pointers...

Comment: ...used a common representation, every variable could be tracked by the compiler as either an N-level indirect pointer to int, char, float, or double, or as an array (of arbitrary size) of such pointers.  Thus, if one limited indirection to 31 levels, a `char` would suffice to hold the type of any variable or struct member. Certainly, being able to have bona fide multi-dimensional array objects without needing to have an array of row pointers is useful, but having a smaller compiler, or having more space to include peephole optimizations within the compiler itself, would have been useful too.

Comment: @supercat Thanks for verifying that you read that, earlier. Mostly, I wanted you to refresh your memory (and mine) about the dates and times and evolution of C, relative to the PDP-11, which was a radical (I mean that in a profound way) departure from earlier instruction set designs. (I have to stop at this point because I've about 6 different tasks pressing at me for some hours yet and I need to attend them.)